# Really simple(?) jquery/json mistake? A syntax error and advice for output needen

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm trying to get a json string back from my controller, that is prefill-values for a jqGrid column.

```
    $("#dagbok_grid").setColProp("Kalla", { editoptions: { value: 

        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetKalla", "Dagbok")', { }, function (data) {
            alert("sdf");
            //What to do here, to get the json string here?
        });

    } });
```

I have two problems, I suspect that they are connected. I'm getting a syntax error in the javascript above. Also, How do I output the data that is returned from the controller action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous. That's what the first A in the acronym stands for. The `$.getJSON` method doesn't return what you think. This method triggers an AJAX request and returns immediately. The result of this request will be available much later in the success callback. So you cannot simply assign the `value` property to `$.getJSON` as you did.

You should first send an AJAX request and then invoke the `setColProp` method inside the success callback:

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetKalla", "Dagbok")', { }, function (data) {
    // The AJAX call succeeded, the data parameter will contain the JSON
    // object returned by your controller action. You can now assign it to
    // the value
    $('#dagbok_grid').setColProp('Kalla', {
        editoptions: {
            value: data
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, I should have noticed that myself. I was so into getting the string to the setColProp instead of doing it the other way around!